# Is there an application I can show a client the speed of their site via differring internet connections?

Tags: html

I have a new client with an old website using massive amounts of tables and inline styles. Some page weigh over 3MB due to huge backgrounds and other large images. I suggested they at least compress the files to speed up the site but they're convinced it's fast. Since they have 13Mbit connection at the office everything seems fast.

I'm looking for a tweak, program or web app capable of loading pages at varying speeds so they understand how it might load for slower DSL or (gasp) dialup users.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

For Windows, take a look at NEWT: http://blog.mrpol.nl/2010/01/14/network-emulator-toolkit/

Also, Fiddler can do some network bandwidth simulation: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, try out http://www.loadtestingtool.com/, there are other tools, but WAPT is the easiest I've found. Here's a comprehensive list of tools: http://www.softwareqatest.com/qatweb1.html#LOAD

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I use  http://www.websiteoptimization.com/services/analyze/

It doesn't animate a load at different speeds, but it has this:

```
Connection Rate    Download Time
14.4K   115.10 seconds
28.8K   59.15 seconds
33.6K   51.16 seconds
56K 31.97 seconds
ISDN 128K   12.01 seconds
T1 1.44Mbps 3.96 seconds
```

It also breaks down areas where improvent is needed.